# Python array copy causes memory (re)allocation

Tags: python, memory, copy, pytorch

```
def Scramble_acton(net, ort, inputs, dpinda, hocmat):

   # copies net in ort
   for lr in range(0,6):
      for bi in range(0,BATCHSIZE):
         for no in range(0,int(lrsize[lr][0])):
            if lrsize[lr][1] == 1:
               ort.nx[lr][bi][no] = net.nx[lr][bi][no]
            if lrsize[lr][1] != 1:
               for xi in range(0,int(lrsize[lr][1])):
                  for yi in range(0,int(lrsize[lr][1])):
                     ort.nx[lr][bi][no][xi][yi] = \
                     net.nx[lr][bi][no][xi][yi]
```

Hi guys,
I pass to this function two pytorch neural network models (net and ort), then copy all output values from one (net) to the other (ort). In the process, the memory allocation increases (which I would not expect to happen) and, after some cycle, the program crashes. I tried to use copy.deepcopy to make the copy, but I got the message "Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol".
Thank you,
Alex

This is the model definition:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

   def __init__(self, x):

      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.pool =  nn.MaxPool2d (2,2)
      self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d ( 3,10,5)
      self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d (10,16,5)
      self.fc3 =   nn.Linear (16*5*5,120)
      self.fc4 =   nn.Linear (120,84)
      self.fc5 =   nn.Linear (84,10)

      lrsize[0][0] =  3;      lrsize[0][1] =32
      lrsize[1][0] = 10;      lrsize[1][1] =14
      lrsize[2][0] = 16*5*5;  lrsize[2][1] = 1
      lrsize[3][0] = 120;     lrsize[3][1] = 1
      lrsize[4][0] =  84;     lrsize[4][1] = 1
      lrsize[5][0] =  10;     lrsize[5][1] = 1

      self.nx = np.empty(6, dtype=np.object)
      self.nl = np.empty(6, dtype=np.object)
      self.nl[1] = self.conv1
      self.nl[2] = self.conv2
      self.nl[3] = self.fc3
      self.nl[4] = self.fc4
      self.nl[5] = self.fc5
      self.forward(x,0,0)

   def forward(self, x0, opt, sitnx):

      #Tanhact # torch.sigmoid
      xx = self.nx; xx[0] = x0
      if opt == 1: xx = sitnx
      self.nx[1] = self.pool(Tanhact(self.conv1(xx[0])))
      self.nx[2] = self.pool(Tanhact(self.conv2(xx[1])))
      self.nx[2] = self.nx[2].view(-1, 16*5*5)
      xt = self.fc3(xx[2]); self.nx[3] = Tanhact(SLOPETP*xt)
      xt = self.fc4(xx[3]); self.nx[4] = Tanhact(SLOPETP*xt)
      xt = self.fc5(xx[4]); self.nx[5] = Tanhact(SLOPETP*xt)
```

nx[] contains the layer values,
BATCHSIZE = 25

I come from C, I just wanted to make a copy of the tensor /array, but something strange is happening here.

[image: call stack between 3rd and 4th for]

Comment: Hello. Just to clarify, how big is your input?

Comment: Hi Luis Flavio, I've edited the post

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. I am not sure, but could it be that the allocation is actually necessary? Are you using any IDE, if so maybe try and debug somewhere around the third or fourth for and check the call tree?

Comment: I've added a picture (snapshot of pycharm debugger), I see nothing strange .... Honestly, I don't understand why memory (re)allocation would be necessary here: I am passing to the function an already allocated network, I just want to modify some values :-(